# Symfony and Percona

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, percona

Does Symfony 2 support Percona? Or should I stick to MySQL ?  I'm running Debian 6 (squeeze) and have MySQL installed but before I install Symfony was thinking maybe Percona would be better (faster) deal?

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percona is just a fork of MySQL that is rebased on each release/version. So you get the exact same features as MySQL, but also get extra performance.

Yes, you can use a Percona Server just like a MySQL server with doctrine.